# Throwing Custom Exception back to caller using camel

Tags: junit, exception, apache-camel

I have created a custom Exception to handle my business scenario need to push this exception back to the caller if the validation fails

Router call definition

```
from(jettyEndpoint_incSubsCnt)
 .doTry().bean(MyProcessor.class).doCatch(MyException.class).bean(MyThrowableException.class);
```

My  Junit Implementation

`try{template.sendBody(new Gson().toJson(myrequest,
                MyRequest.class));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`

I am throwing a customException in MyProcessor

```
if(errors.hasErrors()){
        throw new MyException(ChangeSub_routerClli,errors.getAllErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage());
    }
```

My Custom Exception class

```
public class MyException extends Exception{

private int exceptionID;

public MyException(int exceptionID) {
    super();
    this.exceptionID = exceptionID;
}

public MyException() {

}


public MyException(int exceptionID,String message) {
    super(message);
    this.exceptionID = exceptionID;
}


public MyException(int exceptionID,String message,Throwable exception){
    super(message,exception);
    this.exceptionID = exceptionID;
}


@Override 
public String toString() { 
    return super.toString(); 
} 

@Override 
public String getMessage() { 
    return super.getMessage() + " for Exception ID :" + exceptionID; 
}


public int getExceptionID() {
    return exceptionID;
}}
```

My throwable class implementation

```
public class MyThrowableException implements Processor{
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyThrowableException.class);
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Exception exception = (Exception) exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT);

    log.error(exception);

    throw exception;
}}
```

My Logs are

```
   Logs :::[qtp2078517710-16 - myURL?exchangePattern=InOut] ERROR MyException  - MyException: routerClli is required. for Exception ID :200
```

I am not able to throw back the exception back to the caller

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. you are missing an `.end()` at the end of your catch block
2. if you want to "re-throw" the exception to propagated it to the caller, you need to mark the exception as not handled: `.handled(false)`

Check out the documentation on [try-catch](http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html).